# Is there a java "regular expression" library that supports arbitrary sequences of objects, rather than just strings (sequences of chars)?

Tags: java, regex

Obviously, the match operators would probably be limited, and have to be mapped somehow to comparators that were appropriate for whatever sequences of objects being matched.

Comment: If one can consider Scala a "Java Library" then it has Parser-Combinator support...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jautomata.sourceforge.net/ is a FSA library for Java.

> JAuto is a library for creating, manipulating and displaying finite-state automata within the Java platform. Such objects can be used for various purposes:

- learning automata-theoretic concepts, structures and operators,
- modeling and simulating processes,
- **recognizing regular sets,**
- applying rational transductions on words,
- ...